# MongoDB NOT SO SIMPLE find

Tags: javascript, mongodb

**WHAT I WANT TO BUILD:**

I have such stuff in mongo:

```
{
  team1: 'Love',
  team2: 'Popa',
  score: 3
}
{
  team1: 'Love'
  team2: 'Ola'
  score: 1
}
{
  team1: 'Popa'
  team2: 'Ola'
  score: 5
}
{
  team1: 'Popa'
  team2: 'Kola'
  score: 56
}
```

And I have `form` with `2 inputs` like

```
<input type="text" id="team1" placeholder="Team 1">
<input type="text" id="team2" placeholder="Team 2">
```

Soo for example I put in first input team `Love` and in the second team `Popa`

And I want to display scores games with team that was in mongo with that both teams, FOR MY EXAMPLE **this** will be team `Ola` .

If you understand what I want to build please help me create `Posts.find(....` 
Thank you !

**UPDATE:** Thats my idea how to do it
1.

```
    Posts.find({team1: 'Love'}).map(function(item){ return item.team2; });
    Posts.find({team2: 'Love'}).map(function(item){ return item.team1; });
// disaply all team that plays with first team that I put in first input
    Posts.find({team1: 'Popa'}).map(function(item){ return item.team2; });
    Posts.find({team2: 'Popa'}).map(function(item){ return item.team1; });
// disaply all team that plays with first team that I put in first input
// out put will be look like [Popa,Ola] - first team , [Popa,Ola,Kola] - second team
```

2. Create array with words that consists in both arrrays. `[Popa,Ola]`
3. Delete `'Popa'` because `Popa` can't play with `Popa` lol, it's like Team1 vs Team1 `[Ola]`
4. I need to display scores with the both teams, like

Ola vs Love `(1)`, Ola vs Popa `(5)` , and `id` (in mongo) of this games

**UPDATE2 07.11.2015** Solution is not found, please help !

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yep of course , I wll update my post now, give me a minute

Comment: I fear you idea is the most sound one, the problem with this is that you are looking for two distinct rows which have the same theme which is very difficult in any database. However, you could easily break this into two queries instead of 4, combine the team1 and team2 queries. Another way is to map the set of the teams you find for one query and use that as a means to limit the second query so you literally pull out one or two records

Comment: @sammaye like this - `Posts.find({$or : [ {team1: 'Popa' , team1: 'Love'}]}).map(function(item){ return item.team2; });` - ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your collection name is `Posts`

```
db.Posts.find({team1:"Love"}).forEach(function(doc){
    printjson(db.Posts.findOne({team1:"Popa", team2:doc["team2"]}));
})
```

Comment: It did not work, I don't know why, retrun `undefind`

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Posts.ensureIndex({team1:1,team2:1});

var teams = [];

db.Posts.find(
    {$or:[{team1:'Love'},{team2:'Love'}]},
    {team1:1,team2:1,_id:0}
).forEach(function(doc){
    if(doc.team1 === 'Love'){
        teams[teams.length] = doc.team2;
    }else{
        teams[teams.length] = doc.team1;
    }
});

var actualTeams = [];

db.Posts.find(
    {$or:[
        {team1:'Popa', team2:{$in:teams}},
        {team2:'Popa', team1:{$in:teams}}
    ]},
    {_id:0,team1:1,team2:1}
).forEach(function(doc){
    if(doc.team1 === 'Popa'){
        actualTeams[actualTeams.length] = doc.team2;
    }else{
        actualTeams[actualTeams.length] = doc.team1;
    }
});
```

Something like that and `actualTeams` will contain the cross reference and you have done only two queries to the DB.

Comment: `Posts.ensureIndex` doesnt work in mongo 3.0, `Posts..createIndex` - give me error, and without this part of code I have not correct results

Comment: @Qwe well, it was done without testing. It shows the right path. The function for ensureindex is there https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/

Comment: @Qwe I did notice a slight bug actually, maybe that was what's wrong?

Comment: I don't know what's going on but I can't do `Posts.createIndex` , but without that's line of code I have result like `[]` empty array